# Как включить автодополнение в Sublime Text для Sass

Tags: css, sass, sublime-text, text

Когда пишешь код в css файле, то появляется список свойств и при нажатии одной клавиши избавляшь себя от гемора все писать, но теперь я перешел на препроцессор, набираю свойства и ничего не появляется. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно быть в плагинах. 
К примеру, https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sass.